# Use mongoose populate methods but still return ObjectID rather than documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have designed a mongodb schema that A plan has multiple milestones, each milestones has multiple tasks, each task is associated with a external Task document.
Here is my schema design of mongodb implemented in mongoose

```
var PlanSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    plan:[   Milestone  ]
});    
var Milestone = mongoose.Schema({ 
    goal:String,
    tasks: [ 
       { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Task' } 
    ]
});
```

Now the goal is to find all the tasks of certain milestone in a plan,

```
PlanModel
    .findOne({'_id':pid },
       {
          'plan':{ $slice: [ milestone_number, 1 ] },
          'plan.tasks':1,'plan.goal':1 
       }, function(err, doc){
          if(err){ callback(err, null); }
          else {
             callback(null, doc);
          }
});
```

It works, but obviously the tasks retrieved are just a array of Task ObjectID, what I want is the task documents, so I tried the populate methods

```
PlanModel
    .findOne({'_id':pid }, 
             { 
                 'plan':{ $slice: [ number, 1 ] },
                 'plan.tasks':1,'plan.goal':1 
             })
    .populate('Task', 'task_description ')
    .exec( function(err, doc){
        if(err){callback(err, null);}
        else {
            callback(null, doc);
        }
    })
```

But all I get is still the array of Task ObjectID, rather than the array of Task documents.
Is there anything I do wrong with the populate methods in mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the path to populate to the `populate` call instead of the model name:

```
PlanModel.findOne({'_id':pid }, { 'plan':{ $slice: [ number, 1 ] }, 'plan.tasks':1,'plan.goal':1 })
  .populate('plan.tasks', 'task_description')
  .exec( function(err, doc) { 
    if(err){
      callback(err, null);
    } else { 
      callback(null, doc); 
    } 
  }
)
```

Comment: .populate('plan.tasks', 'task_description') , I got empty array.  whereas populate('tasks', 'task_description') still return a array of ObjectID

Comment: my mongoose version is 3.6.11